# I can't seem to figure out how to manipulate the browser history

Tags: javascript, browser-history

So what I am trying to do is change data based on the navigation of a user. I have 6 main category pages. From those 6 main category pages, I have 12 sub categories that the user can select.

#### What I am trying to achieve:

Let's say the user selects category one.

- The user selects sub-category 1 from category 1.
- The sub-category page is shown and removes the data not related to category 1.
- The user selects sub-category 2 from sub-category 1 and removes the data not related to category 1.
- The user selects sub-category 3 from sub-category 2 and removes the data not related to category 1.

So I can do the category one to sub-category 1 but how would I do it for lets says sub-category 1 to 2 and from 2 to 3...n times....? Each sub-category has to know which *main* category was last selected.

I have looked at but can't seem to find a solution.

```
window.location.hash
history.pushState("","","");
document.referrer
```

Typically this is a bad design and I understand that but I am limited to what I can do on the server side. So trying to develop a work around....

Comment: why was this down voted three times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to work with these and not getting the desired behavior, I was able to find the best solution through several hours of research. The only alternative I could find for passing around data on the client side between pages.

```
window.location.hash
history.pushState("","","");
document.referrer
```

So lets say the user navigates to category1

You would set a session storage object

```
sessionStorage.setItem('last-category', "category1");
```

The user navigates sub-category 1. You can use this to get the session storage of an object and will show the last set operation for that object.

```
sessionStorage.getItem("last-category"); -> output category1
```

The user navigates sub-category 2

```
sessionStorage.getItem("last-category"); -> output category1
```

The user navigates to category 2
You would set the session storage object again to show category2

```
sessionStorage.setItem('last-category', "category2");
```

The user navigates to sub-category 1

```
sessionStorage.getItem("last-category"); -> output category2
```

Comment: does anyone know the compatibility of sessionStorage on the major browsers?